# Get parameter in totalJS Flow?

Tags: dataflow, total.js

I would like to get parameter on my flow, for example, `http://localhost:8000/?param1=12`.

If i want to recup param1 in my application, how and where can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

- install `httproute` component
- edit route options, add your endpoint e.g. `/endpoint/` + check `respond automatically`
- add `code` component and join it with `HTTP route`
- in the `code` you can use:

```
// now can get a value from query arguments
value.query.param1

// Performs next proccessing
send(0, value);
```

Or you can use `httplistener` component but this component captures all requests. `httplistener` has contain same properties like `httproute`.

Comment: Hi Peter
Thanks for response,

i'm in `index.js` file, on line 1764 and this is here who i want to recup the param from my url, do u have an idea ?

Thanks

Comment: In which `index.js`? If you want to obtain a param from URL where the Flow designer is running then you need to use `httplistener` component. Flow doesn't know about the designer, designer connects to Flow backend only via WebSocket.

Comment: Thanks for answers, i found a method now, thanks anyway